# Mirror a bitmap image

Tags: c, image, bmp, mirror

I would like to know how I can invert an image.
I'm putting together an image, and I want to transform it into bmp format. I already have the header, I just need to invert the image data, because in bmp the image has to be inverted, so that it is printed correctly on the printer.

I got an improved algorithm.
However this code only inverts images with

resolution: 60x60 and bpp = 1.
I want to have as maximum limit for my image, a resolution of 384x120.
Does anyone have any idea how I can improve this code?
In the case of an image whose resolution is 10x10 pixels, would it be that in order to flip line by line, should I reverse 10 bits per line?
Below I present the image and the code.

```
    unsigned char icon[] ={ 
        //HEADER
        0x42, 0x4D,             // 0-1   BM 
        0xF6, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, // 2-5   uint32 filesize (not reliable) 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 6-9   uint32 0
        0x76, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 10-13 uint32 bitmapOffset

        0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 14-17 uint32 info size
        0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 18-21 int32  width
        0x3C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 22-25 int32  height
        0x01, 0x00,             // 26-27 uint16 nplanes
        0x04, 0x00,             // 28-29 uint16 bits per pixel bpp bitCount 
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 30-33 uint32 compression flag
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 34-37 uint32 image size in bytes
        0xC4, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, // 38-41 int32  biXPelsPerMeter 
        0xC4, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x00, // 32-45 int32  biYPelsPerMeter
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 46-49 uint32 colors used
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 50-53 uint32 important color count
        //*********************************************
        //Image data:
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x99, 0x99, 0x33, 0x3B, 0xB8, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xF8, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x33, 0xBB, 0xB3, 0x3B, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 
    0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0x33, 0x8B, 0xBB, 0xB3, 0xBB, 0x3B, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x99, 
    0x99, 0x99, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xB3, 0x3B, 0x3B, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x89, 0x99, 
    0x97, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8B, 0x3B, 0x38, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x99, 0x93, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xB3, 0xB3, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x79, 0x99, 0x8F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x3B, 0x38, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x99, 0x98, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xB3, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x89, 0x99, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0x38, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x99, 0x98, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xB3, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF9, 0x99, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x3B, 0xBF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x89, 0x93, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x38, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x99, 0x9F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xBB, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x99, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x33, 0x8F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF9, 0x99, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xB3, 0xBF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x89, 0x98, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x83, 0x38, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x99, 0x9F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0x3B, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x88, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x88, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x77, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x77, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xF8, 
    0x77, 0xFF, 0x77, 0x77, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x77, 0x77, 0x8F, 0xF8, 0x77, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF7, 0x78, 
    0xF7, 0x78, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x40, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x6F, 0xFF, 0xF4, 
    0x44, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x8F, 0x80, 0x44, 0x44, 0x46, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x07, 
    0xF4, 0x06, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x4F, 0xFF, 0xF4, 
    0x47, 0xF6, 0x46, 0x66, 0x44, 0x4F, 0x84, 0x46, 0x64, 0x44, 0x7F, 0x44, 0x6F, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x48, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x46, 0x66, 0x64, 
    0x48, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x64, 0x0F, 0xF8, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x44, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x46, 0x67, 0x64, 0x4F, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 
    0x4F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x6F, 0x84, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x6F, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x44, 0x46, 0x8F, 0xF6, 0x44, 0x77, 0x44, 
    0x7F, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x76, 0x44, 0x4F, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x76, 0x44, 0x6F, 0xF4, 0x46, 0x77, 0x44, 0x8F, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x48, 0xF7, 0x44, 0xFF, 0x44, 
    0x8F, 0xFF, 0x64, 0x44, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xF8, 0x64, 0x44, 0x44, 0x8F, 0xF6, 0x46, 0xF7, 0x44, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x67, 0x74, 0x44, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x88, 0x44, 
    0xFF, 0xF6, 0x44, 0x44, 0x68, 0xFF, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x44, 0x68, 0xFF, 0xF7, 0x44, 0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xF6, 0x44, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x77, 0x46, 
    0xFF, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x84, 0x47, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xF6, 0x44, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x64, 0x47, 
    0xFF, 0xF4, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x48, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x74, 0x48, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x67, 0x74, 0x44, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x44, 0x48, 
    0xFF, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x77, 0x76, 0x8F, 0x84, 0x44, 0x77, 0x76, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x74, 0x44, 0x4F, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x48, 0xFF, 0xF4, 0x44, 0x4F, 
    0xFF, 0xF7, 0x44, 0x44, 0x40, 0x6F, 0xF6, 0x44, 0x44, 0x40, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0x84, 0x44, 0x7F, 0xFF, 
    0xF4, 0x46, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xF7, 0x66, 0x7F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x44, 0x66, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0x76, 0x44, 0x67, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0x64, 0x8F, 0xFF, 
    0xF6, 0x67, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xF7, 0x06, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0x66, 
    0xFF, 0x64, 0x08, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8B, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x68, 
    0xFF, 0xF7, 0x4F, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE6, 0x6F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x66, 0x7F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0x66, 0x8F, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8B, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x67, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x66, 0x6F, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0x66, 0x8F, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x8B, 0xBB, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x66, 0x67, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xBB, 0xBF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF6, 0x66, 0x6F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x66, 0x66, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 0xBB, 0xB8, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x66, 0x6F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xBB, 0xBB, 
    0xB8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x66, 0x66, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0xBB, 
    0xBB, 0xB8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x86, 0x66, 0x66, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFB, 
    0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0x87, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0xEF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x68, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xF8, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0xBB, 0x66, 0x66, 0x6E, 0x8F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xF8, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 
    0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 
                    };

int getBytesPerRow(int bpp, int width)
{
    switch (bpp)
    {
    case 1: return (width >> 3) + ((width & 0x7) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    case 4: return (width >> 1) + ((width & 0x1) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    case 8: return width;
    case 24: return width * 3;
    default: return -1;
    }
}

void ImageMirror(uchar *bmpBytes, int width, int height, int lenght, int bpp)
{

    int32 bmpRowLength;
    int32 imgRowLength;
    int32 imgRow;

    struct ImageInfo imageInfo;

    imageInfo.width = width;
    imageInfo.height = height;
    imageInfo.bpp = bpp;

    // imRowLength is the number of bytes that represent each line
    // bmpRowLength is the length of line in pixels and should be rounded to the next 32 bits boundary
    imgRowLength = getBytesPerRow(imageInfo.bpp, imageInfo.width);
    bmpRowLength = (imgRowLength & 0xFFFC) + ((imgRowLength & 3) == 0 ? 0 : 4);

    imageInfo.imageLength = imgRowLength * imageInfo.height;

    imageInfo.imageBytes = wabaVm->Malloc(imageInfo.imageLength);

    // invert the image, so it's stored upside up
    for (imgRow = 0; imgRow < imageInfo.height; imgRow++)
    {
        // if row size is less than the number of pixels per row
        int index = imgRow * imgRowLength;
        uchar *bmpRow = &bmpBytes[(imageInfo.height - imgRow - 1) * bmpRowLength];
        uchar *imgRow = &imageInfo.imageBytes[index];
        memcpy(imgRow, bmpRow, imgRowLength);
    }
    memset(bmpBytes, 0, lenght);
    memcpy(bmpBytes, imageInfo.imageBytes, lenght);
    Free(imageInfo.imageBytes);
}
```

Comment: If this is a 24-bit bitmap, you have to read one row at a time, flip each row, move to the next row. I am not sure how your current code works for flipping vertically. `bpp`, `width`, and `height` are ignored, `length` is not explained. Show the code which reads the bitmap, explain if it's a 24-bit bitmap or not.

Comment: I think you can just make the `height` field negative to flip the image...

Answer (score 1):

You have a 4-bit bitmap. That means each pixel is 4 bits, and 2 pixels (8 bits) are packed in to one byte. Flipping the row gets complicated because you also have to flip each byte.

In addition, 4-bit bitmap (as well as 1-bit and 8-bit) have palette table appearing after bitmap file header and info header. Make sure to skip the palette table, you don't want to flip the palette table. Use an image library if possible. Otherwise use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    int16_t bfType;
    int32_t bfSize;
    int16_t bfReserved1;
    int16_t bfReserved2;
    int32_t bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct {
    int32_t biSize;
    int32_t biWidth;
    int32_t biHeight;
    int16_t biPlanes;
    int16_t biBitCount;
    int32_t biCompression;
    int32_t biSizeImage;
    int32_t biXPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t biYPelsPerMeter;
    int32_t biClrUsed;
    int32_t biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)

unsigned char icon[] = { ... }

int main()
{
    if(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) != 14 || sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) != 40)
    {
        printf("Wrong packing pragma. Make sure structure is packed.");
        return 0;
    }

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpheader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpinfo;

    memcpy(&bmpheader, icon, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    memcpy(&bmpinfo, icon + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));

    int width = bmpinfo.biWidth;
    int height = bmpinfo.biHeight;
    int bpp = bmpinfo.biBitCount;
    int width_in_bytes = ((width * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4;
    int image_size = width_in_bytes * height;
    int palette_size = 0;
    switch(bpp)
    {
    case 1: palette_size = 2 * 4; break;
    case 4: palette_size = 16 * 4; break;
    case 8: palette_size = 256 * 4; break;
    default:break;
    }

    int palette_offset = sizeof(bmpheader) + sizeof(bmpinfo);
    int bits_offset = palette_offset + palette_size;

    unsigned char *palette = &icon[palette_offset];
    unsigned char *bits = &icon[bits_offset];
    unsigned char *invert = malloc(image_size);

    //copy byte by byte:
    //try this loop first to make sure the bitmap is copied correctly
    for(int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        int offset = y * width_in_bytes;
        for(int x = 0; x < width_in_bytes; x++)
        {
            invert[offset + x] = bits[offset + x];
        }
    }

    //now lets try to flip the bitmap
    //this loop is for 4-bit bitmap only 
    if(bpp == 4)
    {
        //track the padding:
        int gap = width_in_bytes - width / 2;

        for(int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            int offset = y * width_in_bytes;
            for(int x = 0; x < width_in_bytes; x++)
            {
                int src = offset + x;
                int dst = offset + width_in_bytes - x - 1 - gap;

                if(dst < 0 || dst >= image_size)
                    continue;

                invert[dst] = bits[src];

                //2 4-bit pixels are packed in to one byte, swap the pixels:
                unsigned char p = invert[dst];
                invert[dst] = ((p & 0x0F) << 4) | ((p & 0xF0) >> 4);
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *fout = fopen("bmp.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite(&bmpheader, sizeof(bmpheader), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&bmpinfo, sizeof(bmpinfo), 1, fout);
    fwrite(palette, palette_size, 1, fout);
    fwrite(invert, 1, width_in_bytes * height, fout);

    free(invert);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```